# Can anyone think of a way I can error check this?

Tags: c++, arrays, char, conditional-statements

Here is the situation:

My program reads user-input into two char arrays (not allowed to use strings). The user inputs info like this: 
word;word

I do this with a do-while loop that has the condition that while the temp character that is being read into isn't ; to keep going cin << temp and assigning temp to the next char in the array. Then I load the second char array with a cin.get(variableName, 100, '\n').

I want to error check so that if the user doesn't enter words in the format word;word then they'll get an error message. Does anyone know what conditions I can set to check for this? I'm assuming they wouldn't enter word;word;word;word;word or anything but they might just enter word with no ;.

Comment: Assuming C++11 compiler, you could validate the input using `<regex>`. Which brings me to my second point: don't use char arrays (they're evil), use `std::string`.

Comment: "not allowed to use strings" This smells like homework. Is it homework? If yes, tag it as such. Also tagging as C seems wrong here.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Removing C tag, I agree. Adding homework tag, I don't because IIRC it's been deprecated.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Apparently we can't tag homework, i.e. I've tried to edit the tags but it wouldn't let me use that.

Comment: Please edit your post to show what you have tried and where the debugger shows your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even without c++11 and regex, validating the input should be fairly straightforward:

1. Count semicolons entered in both strings.  There should be only one.
2. `strlen` of both arrays should be >= 1.
3. `strlen` of both arrays should be <= array size-1.
4. If only certain types of chars are allowed (eg, no spaces or
   punctuation), scan both arrays for prohibited characters.